# Get /index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

So I'm using node.js to serve a express webserver.

I'm able to catch https://my.site.com/information:

```
express.use('/information',function(req,res) {

})
```

but I'm not able to catch https://my.site.com/information.html like this:

```
express.get('/information.html',function(req,res) {
  // not working
})
```

How can I get **one catch** to get information `AND` information.html - maybe using regex or something like this.. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `get`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method):

> The path for which the middleware function is invoked; can be any of:
>
> - A string representing a path.
> - A path pattern.
> - A regular expression pattern to match paths.
> - An array of combinations of any of the above.

So you can provide a regular expression for this:

```
app.get(/\/information(?:\.html)?$/, (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess You can use built-in feature `res.sendFile()` and combine it with `req.baseUrl` to do this.
Something like that should work:

```
express.use('/information', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + req.baseUrl + '.html'));
});
```

[Second result from Google](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files)

Comment: As 've mentioned if theres a file information.html it will not be catched. Not working.

Comment: @jonas00, actually it depends on what do You exactly need to have in response, could You please describe what do You want to do and which exactly data You need?

Comment: @jonas00 sorry it was a misunderstand about what You need to do :) Quentin's answer is just perfect.